Retrieve Graph API access token to send e-mail
I've built an Azure function to be able to retrieve my Graph API token so that I could send email with it. The goal was that someone else in the company didn't have to manually visit Graph Explorer everyday to retrieve the token and paste it.
I'm using this code to retrieve the token.
private static async Task<string> GetGraphAccessToken(ILogger log)
{
    var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");
    var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret");
    var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId");

    var tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
    });

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, body);
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var tokenResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent);

    return tokenResult.access_token;
}

The issue is: I'm getting a token back, but the token doesn't match the one from the Graph Explorer that is listed under:
enter image description here
I'm having a hard time figuring out why the two token don't match. I've tried using the token I'm being returned to send an email, but I'm getting a bad request response.

From the below line your using the client credential flows which means you need to have App-Only permissions as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/permissions-consent-overview
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),

The Graph Explorer will be using delegate permissions so the token won't be the same. If you want to look at what's inside the token and what permissions it has to which resources use jwt.io
If you want to send mail using your application then you need to grant the Application permission for the clientid your using in
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");

What you should then see in the token is Mail.Send in the Roles eg

Form a security point of view it also best practice you scope the App down to just being able to access the mailbox it needs see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Thank you for the answer, but I'm still confused. It's my first time working with the entra ID permissions. I have given the Application Mail.Send permissions to my API. Do I need to give the Delegated permissions instead?

No because your using the Client Credential flow all you need is App Permission and you need to have consented to the Application in Azure.  But the token you get for App permission will look different from what you see in the Graph Explorer because that is always using Delegated user permissions.
